# Laravel eloquent join in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

**Hi. How can i get laravel eloquent join in ajax success function ?**

this is User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'country', 'type', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    function products(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\ProductModel" , "user_id");
    }
}
```

and this is my products model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','category','title','description','photo','price'
    ];
    public $timestamps = true;

    function author(){
        return $this->hasOne("App\User", "id", "user_id");
    }
}
```

this is controller function

```
public function getProduct(){
        $product= ProductModel::all();
        return response()->json($product);
    }
```

and this is my ajax function

```
$.get("{{route('get.product')}}", function(data){
     console.log(data)  // console array on obj
     $(data).each(function(index,element){
        console.log(element.author)     // console undefined
     })
});
```

on laravel blade its works grate but on ajax does not work

Comment: when you console.log(data) how does the data look like?

Comment: There were arrays in the object. But in the arrays there was no author. The problem has already been solved with the help of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the `author` relationship:

```
$product = ProductModel::with('author')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the responded data do not contain the relation `author`. You have to load the relation first on the server before sending data to client (browser).

This is where [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) come into play:

```
$product = ProductModel::with('author')->get();
```