# php - laravel & ajax: Live update of blade data by setInterval

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent, setinterval

I hope that data in the blade can be updated regularly through setInterval, because the data will enter the database through other places, I want to get the Model data from the Controller, and send the dataset to ajax to update the eloquent data in the view

1.ajax ->success:function doesn't work. (Fixed, by Angel Miladinov -> Statement problem)

2.I use $('#todos-list').empty() to clear content in  . And I have to reload data from eloquent dataset with  .
How to correct the code below

```
success:function(response){
        
                $('#todos-list').empty();
                alert($todotableDataSet);
            if(response.todotableDataSet.length>0){
            var todotableDataSet ='';
            for(var i=0;i<response.todotableDataSet.length;i++){
                todotableDataSet=todotableDataSet+'<td>'+response.todotableDataSet[i]+'</td>';
            }
         }
       }
```

3.Is this code necessary (In CrudController) $todotableDataSet = Todo::with('index')->get();   The code I refer to from here [Laravel eloquent join in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110635/laravel-eloquent-join-in-ajax)

here is CrudController.php

```
class CrudController extends Controller {
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $todotableDataSet = Todo::all();
    return view('home')->with('tableDataSetURL',$todotableDataSet);
   $todotableDataSet = Todo::with('index')->get();
    if($request->ajax()){
    return response()->json($todotableDataSet);
  }}}
```

Here is Model - Todo.php

```
class Todo extends Model
protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];
```

Here is web.php

```
Route::get('/', [CrudController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/tableDataSetURL', [CrudController::class, 'index']);
Route::resource('tableDataSetURL', CrudController::class);
```

Here is todo.js

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

setInterval(function(){
    
    $.ajax({
       url:'/tableDataSetURL',
       type:'GET',
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(response){
        
                $('#todos-list').empty();
            if(response.todotableDataSet.length>0){
            var todotableDataSet ='';
            for(var i=0;i<response.todotableDataSet.length;i++){
                todotableDataSet=todotableDataSet+'<td>'+response.todotableDataSet[i]['body']+'</td>';
            }
         }
       },error: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
    })
 }, 10000);});
```

Here is home.blade.php

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-inverse">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="todos-list" name="todos-list">
            @foreach ($tableDataSetURL as $dataSetinBlade)
            <tr id="todo{{$dataSetinBlade->id}}">
                <td>{{$dataSetinBlade->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$dataSetinBlade->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$dataSetinBlade->description}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
</div>
```

Comment: so what is the problem ? What's the thing that doesn't work ? We need to know so we could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major hole in the controller logic.

> `return` exits the function which means that when you call **return
> view**, as you are calling it now it will never reach the epxression
> which checks if the request is ajax.

**The statement with the ajax should be before the return view statement.**

I recommend to test with the [Network](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) tab of your browser to check whether you are making requests to the `tableDataSetURL` url and what response does it return.

**But I would not recommend doing live udppates this way in the first place.**

> For live update I suggest checking Laravel's [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#introduction) section
> in the documentation. I have implemented live updates with pusher and
> Echo before.
> **It updates the DOM only when a given event occures**, which removes the need for making unnecessary requests to the server when they are
> not needed, just because you don't know if there is any new data or
> not.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me "The statement with the ajax should be before the return view statement", it does fix a problem.